# (In)complete Metric Space and Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function $f:S\to \Bbb R$, where $S \subset \Bbb R$, be a uniformly continuous function and $S$ is not complete. If $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset S$ is a Cauchy sequence whose limit is not in $S$, will we have $f(x_n)$ be convergent?

It is obvious that the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, but will the limit be in $f(S)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d(x,y) =|\arctan x-\arctan y|$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $x_n = n$ is Cauchy, but has no limit. The identity function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Sorry for the noise ...

Comment: @DavidMitra: No problem. I frequently miss something obvious in my answers.

Comment: Indeed, my final goal is to prove that a uniform continuous function $f$ transform any convergent sequence in $S$, even one whose limit does not belong to $S$, to a convergent sequence. Is it true? I do NOt think so, especially when the limit is not in $S$.

Comment: @Scorpio19891119: What do you mean by a convergent sequence whose limit does not belong to $S$?

Comment: @copper.hat In fact, that is a point I do not understand. But the book says so...

Comment: @Scorpio19891119: What book? Convergent only makes sense if there is something to converge to. Uniformly convergent functions transform Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Maybe the book means a cauchy sequence wich does not converge in $S$, but every cauchy sequence converges in the closure of $S$, so in that sence we have "convergent" sequences whose limits do not belong to $S$.

Comment: @sranthrop: That would be a reasonable interpretation...

Answer (score 2):

Consider $S=(0,1)$, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, and $f(x)=x$

Comment: But $f(x_n)$ IS a convergent sequence of real numbers!

Comment: The limits is not in S= $f(S)$